# Calculating used memory by a set of processes on Linux

Tags: c++, c, linux, memory, posix

I'm having trouble with calculating the actually used memory (resident) by a set of processes.

The issue that just came up is a user with a set of processes that share memory between themselves, so a simple addition of used memory ends up with a nonsense number (>60gb when the machine only has 48gb memory).

Is there any simple way to approach this problem?

I can probably do some approximation. Take `(res mem - shared mem) * num proc + shared mem`. But not all processes necessarily share the same memory block.

I'm looking for a POSIX or Linux solution to this problem for C/C++.

Comment: Far from an answer, but I think you could determine what processes share what memory based on `/proc/${PID}/maps`.

Comment: You can also try the [ps](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?ps) command, which displays memory used by different processes.

Comment: @ArunR I don't see such option in ps, could you please provide it in an answer?

Comment: Can you try `ps v`. Also `top` command should list the top 30(I think) cpu users, with info on their mem usage.

Comment: @ArunR Great, please read the question first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will want to iterate through each processes `/proc/[pid]/smaps`

It will contain an entry for each VM mapping of the likes:

```
7ffffffe7000-7ffffffff000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
Size:                100 kB
Rss:                  20 kB
Pss:                  20 kB
Shared_Clean:          0 kB
Shared_Dirty:          0 kB
Private_Clean:         0 kB
Private_Dirty:        20 kB
Referenced:           20 kB
Anonymous:            20 kB
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
Swap:                  0 kB
KernelPageSize:        4 kB
MMUPageSize:           4 kB
```

`Private_Dirty` memory is what you are interested in.

If you have the `Pss` field in your `smaps` file then this is the amount of resident memory divided by the amount of processes that share the physical memory.

`Private_Clean` could be copy-on-write mappings. Those are commonly used for shared libraries and are generally read/no-write/execute.

Comment: Man, I sort of hoped that there would be something slightly simpler :-D But well, thanks for the info :-)

Comment: @Let_Me_Be in `bash` (set `$PIDS` comma separated pids): `grep -h -s Pss: /proc/{$PIDS}/smaps | awk '{sum += $2}END{print sum " kB"}'`